# <form onsubmit="function();"> is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  function make_alert() {
    var text = $('#text_').val(); //let suppose it as true
    if (true) {
      alert("yes_text");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("no_text");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return make_alert()">
 <textarea id="text_">
 </textarea>
 <button id="btn_submit" type="submit" name="type" value="create_first">
 Submit
 </button>
</form>
```

This code is alerting when I click submit button.

I write `onsubmit` in the html `form` tag, but It seems not working.

How can I do this?

What I want to is that I can treat some stuff before `form post`. So I think I need those functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The make_alert function is not "global" so it can't be found.

Here's one solution

```js
  var make_alert = (function() {
    var text = $('#text_').val(); //let suppose it as true
    if (true) {
      alert("yes_text");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("no_text");
      return false;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return make_alert()">
  <textarea id="text_">
  </textarea>
  <button id="btn_submit" type="submit" name="type" value="create_first">
                        Submit
                    </button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this. Remove function from  $(function() {

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKdrdK

```
function make_alert() {
    var text = $('#text_').val(); //let suppose it as true
    if (true) {
      alert("yes_text");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("no_text");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

for me, it was because I put the required attribute which prevents onsubmit=""